# Getting error "Failed to establish a new connection" when sending message to TelegramBot using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm, telegram-bot

I'm using TelegramBot API to send a message to specific chat using requests library.

```
http_post = requests.post(self.bot_url + self.send_msg_method,
data={'chat_id': self.chat_id, 'text': str(message)})
```

I'm debugging my code (PyCharm) and **it's working- for the first time only**.
All the following calls to the same code will lead to the error:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /botXXX:XXXX/sendMessage
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions',))

Any idea what causes the error ?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to use [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: @ovs - the same error. It's not about telegram, probably it is related to https...

Answer (score 1):

The issue caused by local security settings.
McAfee for some reason blocks these request when I'm not on corporate network.