# Telegram Bot not able to send message. The same bot was sending earlier

Tags: telegram-bot

I had created a telegram bot sometime back and it was working fine and sending message to required telegram group. But now its erroring out while sending messages.

when trying google URL its working fine and getting response 200.

```
  import requests
  requests.get('https://google.com')
```

But when trying below telegram URL

```
  import requests
  requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot123444342:ADDSAFxasdfewwwqrraa-kDE/getUpdates')
```

getting error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: /bot123444342:ADDSAFxasdfewwwqrraa-kDE/getUpdates (Caused 
by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 
0x0000018439602610>:Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

tried solution given in

```
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/528
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045725/getting-error-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-when-sending-message-to-tel
Tried disabling the firewall and trying. Tried using VPN
```

All failed. Any other solutions?